# Page loads image slide off screen on loading

Tags: jquery

I have a problem on this page that I don't understand. When this page loads http://www.transurban.co.nz/index.htm everything is fine, but if the page loads from just the domain name http://www.transurban.co.nz, the index.htm file is being ignored and the slider image(s) are offset by the width of the image (it seems). If the home page is opened via an internal page using the main navigation it all works perfectly. The slider is being controlled by jquery-superslides.js I don't know where to start looking to see why this is happening. Any ideas on what is causing this problem would  be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<!--start of hero slider -->
<div class="sliderBox">
    <div class="wide-container">
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides-container">
                <div class="innerSlideTextBox ">
                    <img src="images/slider/bg1.jpg" alt="Transurban project" />
                </div>
                <div class="innerSlideTextBox">
                    <img src="images/slider/bg2.jpg" alt="Transurban project" />
                </div>
                <div class="innerSlideTextBox">
                    <img src="images/slider/bg3.jpg" alt="Transurban project" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="slides-navigation">
                <div class="innerPositioning">
                    <!--  <a href="#" class="next"></a>-->
                    <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end of hero slider -->


$('#slides').superslides({
    inherit_width_from: '.wide-container',
    inherit_height_from: '.wide-container',
    hashchange: true,
    play: 7000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem wasn't a code issue. There was a duplicate index file, index-hold.htm that was set as the default index and this was causing the confusion.